# Chart.js 3.5: linear gradient doesn't apply properly when multiple bars in the same chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm applying a linear gradient to barcharts the way described in the doc successfully.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html
In the case I have 2 datasets or more as bar types each, I want to apply different color gradients to each dataset.

I have tried adding a second function called getGradient2 or to pass the colors as parameters as shown below, however the render ignores the second colors and apply the first gradient to all datasets

```
let width, height, gradient;
    function getGradient(ctx, chartArea, start_color, stop_color) {
        const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
        const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
        if (gradient === null || width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
            // Create the gradient because this is either the first render
            // or the size of the chart has changed
            width = chartWidth;
            height = chartHeight;
            gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.bottom, 0, chartArea.top);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, stop_color);
            gradient.addColorStop(1, start_color);
        }
        return gradient;
    }
```

Then the implementation:

```
data: data_array[0],
    borderRadius: { topLeft: 100, topRight: 100, bottomRight: 100,  bottomLeft: 100 },
    backgroundColor: function(context) {
                    const chart = context.chart;
                    const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;
                    if (!chartArea) { return null; }
                    return getGradient2(ctx, chartArea, "rgba(182, 86, 235, 1)", "rgba(182, 86, 235, 0.66)");
    }, barPercentage: 1.0, categoryPercentage: 1.0,
    barThickness: 10, maxBarThickness: 10, yAxisID: yAxisID, borderWidth: 0, type: 'bar'
```

And for the second dataset:

```
     data: data_array[1],
          borderRadius: { topLeft: 100, topRight: 100, bottomRight: 100,  bottomLeft: 100 },
          backgroundColor: function(context) {
                    const chart = context.chart;
                    const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;
                    if (!chartArea) { return null; }
                    return getGradient2(ctx, chartArea, "rgba(244, 102, 235, 1)", "rgba(244, 102, 235, 0.66)");
          }, barPercentage: 1.0, categoryPercentage: 1.0,
          barThickness: 10, maxBarThickness: 10, yAxisID: yAxisID, borderWidth: 0, type: 'bar'
```

Seems like a bug to me but they say to post on SO on GitHub, so let me know if you find a way to make it work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define this line `let width, height, gradient;` within your function so its bound to the function and wont get overriden then it works just fine:

```js
const getGradient = (ctx, chartArea, start_color, stop_color) => {
  let width, height, gradient;
  const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
  const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
  if (gradient === null || width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
    // Create the gradient because this is either the first render
    // or the size of the chart has changed
    width = chartWidth;
    height = chartHeight;
    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.bottom, 0, chartArea.top);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, stop_color);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, start_color);
  }
  return gradient;
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: function(context) {
          const chart = context.chart;
          const {
            ctx,
            chartArea
          } = chart;
          if (!chartArea) {
            return null;
          }
          return getGradient(ctx, chartArea, "rgba(182, 86, 235, 1)", "rgba(182, 86, 235, 0.66)");
        }
      },
      {
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: function(context) {
          const chart = context.chart;
          const {
            ctx,
            chartArea
          } = chart;
          if (!chartArea) {
            return null;
          }
          return getGradient(ctx, chartArea, "rgba(244, 102, 235, 1)", "rgba(244, 102, 235, 0.66)");
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: indeed it does the trick! I stupidly replicated the sample code from the doc :)